# Stop Liquibase from removing Oracle hints

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I have Oracle statements containing hints. But Liquibase keeps removing them. I guess Liquibase thinks they are block comments ... for some reason.

As such I've tried adding stripComments:false but without any luck.

**Example**

```
--changeset AUTHOR:ID (stripComments:false)
Insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(CUSTOMER,CUSTOMER_PK) */ Into CUSTOMER Values (value1, value2, etc)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to stop Liquibase from removing the Oracle hints?

Answer (score 1):

found the issue, forgot to add stripcomments on one changeset